Highlight column in Excel based on time block
I have an Excel spreadsheet that shows the employee schedule, and I need it to highlight or outline the column based on the current time.  It doesn't have to be date specific and I am fine with it highlighting the entire column. I have my times in 15 minute increments over E12:AZ12.
I have tried conditionally formatting E12:AZ103 with the formula:
=AND(HOUR($E12)=HOUR(NOW()),MINUTE(E12)=(IF(MINUTE(NOW())<15,0,15)))
But it is not highlighting anything.


This will only hit a TRUE if it's the current time is between 0 and 30 minutes after the hour. Perhaps something like =ROUND((MINUTE(NOW())/15),0)*15 or =(MATCH(MINUTE(NOW()),{0,15,30,45})-1)*15 would be more appropriate?

Conditional Formatting: Now()'s Time - Exact Match or Next Smaller

Note that this will update only on each calculation!

Select the range E25:AZ103.

Select Home->Conditional Formatting->New Rule.

In the New Formatting Rule form, select Use a formula to determine which cells to format.

In the box below "Format values where this formula is true", enter the following formula:
=E$12=XLOOKUP(MOD(NOW(),1),$E$12:$AZ$12,$E$12:$AZ$12,,-1) 


Select the Format button, choose a format, and press OK twice to confirm.



Screenshot Formula (Covers from 8:00 AM to 7:45 AM (Next Day))
=E$12=XLOOKUP(MOD(NOW(),1),$E$12:$CV$12,$E$12:$CV$12,,-1)

Interesting

It misbehaved when rows were hidden like the screen didn't update i.e. the first visible rows updated while the rows below the hidden rows didn't. Showing the rows (and hiding them again (irrelevant)) fixed the issue.


That perfectly highlighted the time that I was in!  Is there a way to have it continually calculate and update?

I don't think that formulas could achieve this. In VBA, you could use the Application.OnTime method. BTW, pressing F9, Del, adjusting the column width, and whatnot force the calculation of the sheet.

Assuming your time slots are based on date & time, Could you give this a try?

Select the range containing the time slot and name it time_slots
Name the first cell in the range for conditional formatting slot_now - make sure it is in relative form (A2 not $A$2).


Select range for conditional formatting with the first cell selected, enter the following:
=AND(NOW() >= INDEX(time_slots,, COLUMN(slot_now)), NOW() < INDEX(time_slots,, COLUMN(slot_now)) + TIME(0,15,0))

Expanded form, I think the logic is easy to follow:
=AND(
    NOW() >=
        INDEX(
            time_slots,
            ,
            COLUMN(slot_now)
        ),
    NOW() <
        INDEX(
            time_slots,
            ,
            COLUMN(slot_now)
        ) + TIME(0, 15, 0)
)

Conditional formatting for the example:

Result - will update with each change in the sheet; you can also press F9 to force the update:

